# Parse issue, expected a type after copying files

Tags: ios

I am trying to use the SWTableViewCell files from https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

Just after copying the files to my project folder, there are many errors at files NSMutableArray+SWUtilityButtons.h and .m

[image]

I don't know what to do, I have used these files in other projects without any issue.

I would appreciate any help to solve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `@import UIKit;` to the header of that file.